# Are the 2020 ESM "coronavirus" MoUs substantially the same as the 2012-2013 ESM MoUs?

Tags: european-union, covid-19, international-monetary-fund, esm

It's been asserted (more specifically now) in [an answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/52758/18373) to another question here that the 2012 (actually Jan 2013) ESM MoUs are effectively the same as the 2020 ESM "coronavirus" MoUs.

Reasons I'm suspicious of this claim: first the passage quoted in that answer ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Stability_Mechanism)) seems to have an entirely wrong/implausible focus in 2020, i.e.

> The signed conditional MoU agreement will focus on requirements for fiscal consolidation and structural reforms to improve the sovereign financial stability.

I can't see a 2020 "coronovarus" MoU still emphasizing fiscal consolidation as the *primary goal*.

Second, the Wikipedia page mentions (as a preamble to the above statement) the IMF as being involved:

> When applying for ESM support, the country in concern will be analyzed and evaluated on all relevant financial stability matters by the so-called Troika (European Commission, ECB and IMF)

So, do the 2020 ESM "coronavirus" MoUs have (1) the same emphasis on fiscal consolidation (as the 2013 ones), and (2) do they [still] call for a role for the IMF in the process?

(I see there has been [a lot](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/BRIE/2014/497755/IPOL-ECON_NT(2014)497755_EN.pdf) of "water under bridge" in terms of ESM proposals/developments since 2013, but I haven't digested all that to answer my own question, yet.)

Comment: Regarding your "water under the bridge" link: the EP has nothing to say about the ESM. The ESM is a separate treaty between the countries that make up the Euro, totally separate from the EU and its parliament.

Comment: @Sjoerd: "nothing to say" in the sense that they don't get to decide anything. They did put out an "in depth analysis" of the ESM.